# Toggle not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, jsp, toggle

I want to list the detailed info of what the user clicks, but the info is shown only in the first `tr`, and the values are the same even if I clicked either the 2nd or 3rd button.

**home.jsp**

```
<%@include file="/common/header.jsp" %>
<main>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>r_no</th>
            <th>r_start</th>
            <th>r_end</th>
            <td><input type="button" value="ADD"
                onclick="location.href='insert.do'"></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${routelist}" var="list">
            <tr>
                <td>${list.r_no}</td>
                <td>${list.r_start}</td>
                <td>${list.r_end}</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="EDIT"
                    onclick="location.href='update.do?r_no=${list.r_no}'"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="DELETE"
                    onclick="location.href='delete.do?r_no=${list.r_no}'"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="DETAILED" class="btn"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><aside>
                    <ul>
                        <li>r_pay_adult : ${list.r_pay_adult}</li>
                        <li>r_pay_teen : ${list.r_pay_teen}</li>
                        <li>r_pay_kid : ${list.r_pay_kid}</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside></td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</form>
<table width="600">
```

**aside.js**

```
(function($){
$(function(){

    var $aside = $('aside'),
        $btn = $('.btn');
    
    $aside.hide();
    
    $btn.on('click', function(){
         var e = $(this).index();
        
        $aside.eq(e).toggle(500);
         
         if($(this).val()=="DETAILED")
        {
            $(this).val("CLOSE");
        } else {
            $(this).val("DETAILED");
        }
    });
    
});
})(jQuery);
```

Could you tell me how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is what you are indexing with `$(this).index()`.

When no argument is passed to [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) it will return the index of the element *within it's siblings*. Those buttons have no siblings within their respective `<td>` so it will always return `0`

Try indexing the button instance within the whole collection of buttons:

```
var e = $btn.index(this);
```

A more robust solution would be to use data attributes on the buttons

Comment: I tried what you mentioned and it absolutely works. And it got your point why I should use $btn.index(this); Thank you for your help and explanation!